# Jquery UI Sortable multiple select

Tags: javascript, html, css

does anyone know of a native way to implement multiple element select paired with jquery UI sortable

http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection

or do you think i should just whip my own custom solution together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so i got it...

it is a combination of

http://jsfiddle.net/benstenson/qPJFe/

and http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection

http://comp345.awardspace.com/sortable/js/ui.multisortable.js

Comment: hi @nick yup here is the github repo https://github.com/samccone/multi-select-order